# How to implement a list item template that has one control right-aligned without it getting clipped in a virtualizing ListBox?

Tags: wpf

If I scroll down one page, then when resizing this list box by reducing its width, at certain points it starts to clip the right-docked button instead of reducing the width of the text block or redoing the layout.

[image: button shouldn't be clipping]

Note: Swapping the data template from dock panel to grid doesn't fix it and neither does calling InvalidateMeasure or InvalidateArrange in SizeChanged events.

if the user scrolls up again, then back down, then it layouts properly.

Is my XAML wrong? Is this a WPF bug? Is there a way to make this work?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="118" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Foo}">
            <DockPanel>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right">Click!</Button>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="ItemStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}">
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Items = new ObservableCollection<Foo>(Input);
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Foo> Items {get; }

        private static Foo[] Input = new Foo[] {
            new Foo ("four hundred and seventy"),
            new Foo ("five million nine hundred and"),
            new Foo ("two million five hundred and seventy"),
            new Foo ("six million six hundred and"),
            new Foo ("seven million nine hundred"),
            new Foo ("five million three"),
        };
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Text { get; init;}

        public Foo(string text)
        {
            Text = text;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the item to clip?

Comment: @mm8 using the vertical scroll bar click in the bottom gutter to scroll down one "page".  Then using the right-hand side of the  window start dragging to the left to make the window's width smaller. At a window width similar to the screenshot, the button will start to clip.